# Match all possible parts of or ( | ) using NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a regular expression which looks something like this:

```
(\bee[0-9]{9}in\b)|(\bee[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]{2}\b)
```

Now if the input string is `ee123456789ab` then the second part of `|` matches the string. But if the input string is `ee123456789in` first part of `|` consumes the whole string and the second part doesn't get a change to match the string? I want both parts of `|` to have their change to match the string so that I come to know that both parts were able to match the string. Is it even possible to do that using regular expression?

Comment: This example doesn't make much sense. *You* have constructed the regexes. So you know that *every time* the first alternative matches, the second one would also have matched because the first regex is a "subset" of the second regex. Why would you ever need this? Can you think of a more realistic example that shows the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=(ee[0-9]{9}in$)?)(?=(ee[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]{2}$)?)
```

This will capture a match in both `\1` and `\2`; if either of the two is empty, then the corresponding part of the regex has not matched.

I've changed the word boundary anchors to start/end of string anchors since you're testing against the entire string, not just substrings.

In Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r"^(?=(ee[0-9]{9}in$)?)(?=(ee[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]{2}$)?)")
>>> m = r.match("ee123456789ab")
>>> m.group(1)
>>> m.group(2)
'ee123456789ab'
>>> m = r.match("ee123456789in")
>>> m.group(1)
'ee123456789in'
>>> m.group(2)
'ee123456789in'
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # Start of string
(?=             # Look ahead to see if it's possible to match...
 (              # and capture...
  ee[0-9]{9}in  # regex 1
  $             # (end of string)
 )?             # (make the match optional)
)               # End of lookahead
(?=             # Second lookahead, same idea...
 (
  ee[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]{2}
  $
 )?
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with regular expressions.  If any part of it matches, it's considered a match.  You would have to do it with two different expressions and see if both succeeded.

Comment: Of course it's possible unless you're talking about regex engines that don't support lookahead (not many of which are still in use anywhere).

Comment: I am using it in an iOS app and iOS supports lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

An OR is a or no matter what, can't get around that.
As @Tim mentioned it can be done with lookahead(s):

You can stand still and look at the same text more than once.

So, one way is to look at each expression without moving,
each expression is optional. -

```
(?= ( ee [0-9]{9} in )? )
(?= ( ee [0-9]{9} [a-zA-Z]{3} )? )
```

This is bad because, although the position will advance after the last
expression, it will only advance 1 inter-character position. It also
allows overlapp when searching in a global context.

Searches can be sped up by consuming a character -

```
(?= ( ee [0-9]{9} in )? )
(?= ( ee [0-9]{9} [a-zA-Z]{3} )? )
.
```

The engine does an optimization when something is consumed,
advances in chunks (unknown how it decides).

If you have other expressions included with these, it requires that the
position be advanced past here or nothing will match. This could also eliminate
overlapped matching of text (if thats a goal).

Its actually hard to avoid overlap unless you know for sure one expression will
be longer than the other. If thats the case then you could always do a conditional
(if available) to consume the larger text -

```
(?= ( ee [0-9]{9} in )? )
(?= ( ee [0-9]{9} [a-zA-Z]{3} )? )
(?(2) \2 | \1 )
```

And, if you know one is a subset of the other, you could just do this -

```
(?= ( ee [0-9]{9} in )? ) ( ee [0-9]{9} [a-zA-Z]{3} )
```

Either way, depending on the expressions, much thought has to go into designing
consumption into the regex to avoid overlap.

Comment: @AnupamGodbole: You know you can upvote helpful answers, right?